# ActiveMQ Artemis message grouping leader election

Tags: grouping, message, activemq-artemis

We are using a cluster of ActiveMQ Artemis nodes and we want to use the message grouping feature.
From the documentation, we understood that we need to identify 1 node that will be the master for this feature. Is there a way to have this election to be done automatically and dynamically by the cluster itself?

If not, let's say we do it ourselves, is there a way to dynamically change the message grouping setup of a node without having to restart it?

We are using the EmbeddedActiveMQ.

Regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically "elect" the node which will make the message grouping decisions. It must be configured statically. Furthermore, there is no way to change the configuration without restarting the broker(s).

That said, I would encourage you to review this note from the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#clustered-grouping):

> In general, combining clustering and message grouping is a poor choice because the fundamental ideas of grouped (i.e. ordered) messages and horizontal scaling through clustering are essentially at odds with each other.
>
> Message grouping enforces ordered message consumption. Ordered message consumption requires that each message be fully consumed and acknowledged before the next message in the group is consumed. This results in serial message processing (i.e. no concurrency).
>
> However, the idea of clustering is to scale brokers horizontally in order to increase message throughput by adding consumers which can process messages concurrently. But since the message groups are ordered the messages in each group cannot be consumed concurrently which defeats the purpose of horizontal scaling.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I understand your comment. The thing is that we are using our cluster for different use cases. Only one of them requires the message grouping. for the other we need an horizontal scaling. Would you recommend to have 2 differents clusters?

Comment: I would recommend a single node for your grouping needs and then an cluster for your horizontal scaling needs.